# Linguistic journal that allows blind referee

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I'd like to know which journals in linguistics allow papers without author's information to be reviewed by referees. The only one that can do it to my knowledge is Linguistic Inquiry from the MIT Press.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of double-blind reviewed journals in linguistics is very large. In 4 decades I think I have only reviewed maybe two papers with authors identified, and that includes book chapters. Double blind is the norm.

Comment: @MathWizard Follow the journal's instructions. Which will probably say not to put any self identifying information in.

Comment: Editors almost certainly won't change the submitted PDF and probably cannot, given the manuscript management systems they use.

Comment: Your submission will not be made available to the public until it is accepted and you name is made part of the publication. It is also allowed by some journals that you can archive a non_anonymous copy elsewhere.